# Rellenar celdas con datos de otra hoja en excel

Tags: excel

Tengo un archivo de excel con dos hojas, La que se llama Playa Manzanillo es donde se mostrara la informacion que esta en la hoja E.MANZANILLO (La BD).
En la hoja donde esta toda la informacion hago un filtro por fecha y mostraria la info de esta forma, los datos de la columna cantidad_remisionada son lo que se veran en la otra hoja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la Hoja Principal se deberia mostrar asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos que se ven son estaticos los unicos datos que se pones son los que se dan en la BD.

Comment: Hola MIguel. Me temo que a la pregunta le faltan datos para comprender completamente el resultado al que quieres llegar. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es la [Función FILTRAR](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-filtrar-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)